# Check if all values of array match condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know that an empty string would be consider truthy, since only nil and false are considered falsey. But I have an array of empty strings like this:

```
["", "", ""].any?
 => true
```

And I want it to return false if all the strings in the array are empty. One option is to do this:

```
["", "", ""].select {|item| item.present? }.any?
 => false
```

But now I am using two iterators in this example. Is this the only way? Or is there another iterator in the arsenal of tools that suites the job?

Comment: Ruby `Object` doesn't have a present? method Andrew, Rails does, hence the tag.

Comment: @SebastianPalma How do you know `present?` is from Rails and now from some other library or the OP's personal code? It is not you who needs to clarify that, it is the OP. All you can do is guess. Only the OP knows the truth.

Comment: @Donato What is `present?`?

Comment: Alright it is Rails and I will update question.

Comment: You have not stated explicitly that the array is non-empty and contains only strings, but everyone giving answers seemed to have assumed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`any` should take a block, so you should be able to do something like:

```
["", "", ""].any? {|item| item.present?}
```

---

This can be shortened using a [`to_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) method on the `present?` symbol (credit: [@mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/), 2018):

```
['','',''].any?(&:present?)
```

Comment: Or `a.any?(&:present?)`

Comment: You can also use detect If you want to fetch value which satisfy your condition. `["", "", "a"].detect(&:present?)   => "a"`

Comment: Actually `present?` is an incorrect method for ops needs. He specifically wants to check if all the strings are empty and `present?` would give false not only for empty strings, but for nils, empty hashes etc.

Comment: `"".present?` doesn't work on my system; can anyone else confirm or have I lost my mind?

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov perhaps, I was merely using his example to keep things simple. As what /muistooshort/ pointed out, passing the to_proc as an argument would probably be a better answer because of its concision. I’ll update this answer when I’m not a slave to mobile. Thank you both!

Comment: @oMiKeY That may be a feature of Rails. You might need to require active_support (and extensions) to use that method in standalone Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

In my head the logic would be like, "they're not all empty" so I would put

```
arr = ["","",""]

!arr.all?(&:empty?)

=> false
```

Using `.present?` on a string doesn't work in my testing environment.

Comment: it's not ruby native, it's part of the active support library from rails stack

Answer (score 0):

You could write

```
arr.join != ''
```